# What is the difference between group n by vs group n by into g in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I notice that both LINQ query produce the same output. May I know what's difference of these two query for grouping? Is it because `into` can group by 2 element?

```
var groupBy = from n in numbers
              group n by n;
```

And:

```
var groupBy = from n in numbers
              group n by n into g
              select g;
```

Comment: Practically it is for giving names in longer LINQ queries, and `into` also support aggregate functions like `max`, `sum`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference stands out immediately in method syntax:

```
var groupBy = numbers.GroupBy(n => n);
```

vs. (with `into`)

```
var groupBy = numbers.GroupBy(n => n).Select(g => g);
```

Now your example isn't too useful to demonstrate the practical differences because each group is just one item, so let's take this example:

```
var group = from c in Company
            group c by c.City;
```

If this is all we need, listing companies by cities, we're done. But if we want to do anything with the results of the grouping we need `into` and `select`, for example:

```
var group = from c in Company
            group c by c.City
            into cg
            select new
            {
                City = cg.Key,
                NumberOfCompanies = cg.Count()
            };
```

In method syntax:

```
var group = Companies
            .GroupBy(c => c.City)
            .Select(gc => new
            {
                City = cg.Key,
                NumberOfCompanies = cg.Count()
            });
```

Comment: but if I a foreach loop, I can get `Key` and `Count` for both query. 
            foreach (var item in groupBy)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "-" + item.Count());
            }

Comment: Both queries return the same thing because the `Select` doesn't add anything new, `Select(g => g)` is redundant. You only want to add a `Select` call (or `into - select`) if you want to do something special with the results *in one query*.

Answer (score 2):

https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/09/15/query-expression-syntax-continuations/

> When "into" is used after either a "group x by y" or "select x"
>   clause, it’s called a query continuation. (Note that "join … into"
>   clauses are not query continuations; they’re very different.) A query
>   continuation effectively says, "I’ve finished one query, and I want to
>   do another one with the results… but all in one expression."

The into keyword makes your query continuation, it is effectively starting a new query with the results of the old one in a new range variable.

You can also see how [they are Compiled](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBkCWAdgI4DcyyUAzJjOgMLoDey6bmNUALOgLIAUASmat2Y0WLYA3AIYAndIQCuAWwBGAUzkBndAF5FGgO4BtALpM4AGhhXrVG3YC+5JJPayFAczkB7JQAOAEIAnvroAGZ+KoroRIqqmjoSPv4BsWphhK7ubBKSnuipgaF0BlG+MYRx1crqWtqixenVmbFEAC6+RaLaGgA2GgDGHUU57E7ITkA).

Comment: what in regular SQL translates into "doing a subquery"